# Sharing only one content type between 2 websites

Tags: 7, nodes, multi-sites

I have 2 websites set on the same drupal 7.32 instance. There are completely different, with different databases. But I need to show some content from website1 in website2.

I just need to get a list of nodes from the database for website1 with one specific type and list some details about them in website2.

I know I can get all the nodes with a certain type like this:

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => 'node_type_here'));
```

But this (obviously) works within the same site.

Any tips on how I can get them on a different site?

Comment: Are you trying to set up some kind of synchronisation? Or read other site's database directly *(I wouldn't)*? Some kind of live feed?

Comment: @Mołot. No syncronization. I'm just trying to list some entities from website 1 in website 2. I guess you can say it is similar to a live feed.

Comment: Since it's two completly different websites I think it should be done with Migrate module https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate or using xmlrpc.php (more here: http://goo.gl/DEcQJx - chapter 20).

Comment: How often will this occur: Just once, weekly, yearly, whenever a refresh is needed?

Comment: I have no idea how often the data will change. For sure it won't be daily. But that's all I know.

Comment: hey...why the downvote? this is a legit question. a noob question but a legit one. don't hit and run. give a reason at least.

Comment: Upvote. This is a legit question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to share content between sites, you may want to look at the [deploy module](http://drupal.org/project/deploy)....

> The Deploy module is designed to allow users to easily stage content
>   from one Drupal site to another. Deploy automatically manages
>   dependencies between entities (like node references). It is designed
>   to have a rich API which can be easily extended to be used in a
>   variety of content staging situations.

To share a Content Type between sites, look into [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features):

> The features module enables the capture and management of features in
>   Drupal. A feature is a collection of Drupal entities which taken
>   together satisfy a certain use-case.
>
> Features provides a UI and API for taking different site building
>   components from modules with exportables and bundling them together in
>   a single feature module. A feature module is like any other Drupal
>   module except that it declares its components (e.g. views, contexts,
>   CCK fields, etc.) in its .info file so that it can be checked,
>   updated, or reverted programmatically.

Alternatively if you're only trying to share a *list of things*, what about using RSS feeds from Website 1 and using the [Feeds Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) to pull it into Website 2?

> Import or aggregate data as nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records.
>
> One-off imports and periodic aggregation of content Import or
>   aggregate RSS/Atom feeds Import or aggregate CSV files Import or
>   aggregate OPML files PubSubHubbub support Create nodes, users,
>   taxonomy terms or simple database records from import Extensible to
>   import any other kind of content Granular mapping of input elements to
>   Drupal content elements Exportable configurations Batched import for
>   large files

Also as mentioned in the comments the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) Module is worth a look.

> The migrate module provides a flexible framework for migrating content
>   into Drupal from other sources (e.g., when converting a web site from
>   another CMS to Drupal). Out-of-the-box, support for creating core
>   Drupal objects such as nodes, users, files, terms, and comments are
>   included - it can easily be extended for migrating other kinds of
>   content. Content is imported and rolled back using a bundled web
>   interface (Migrate UI module) or included Drush commands (strongly
>   recommended).

Comment: I was hoping of an out of the box way to do it. Will take the feed approach. Seams the less intrusive one. Thanks.

Comment: For a good jump start, look into the YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wasIAbfRls

Comment: Thanks for the video link. it certainly gets the ball rolling for a drupal noob (like myself).